# SetUP Oracle SQL Developer Credentials my new Windows installation

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have downloaded Oracle SQL Developer version 20.4.1.407 from the Oracle site and installed in my Windows 10 machine after extracting it, and created a desktop shortcut.

As i am beginner in sql, i dont have any new database to connect.

Then I launched the SQL Developer application, and clicked on the + button to create a new database connection. In that window I put in:

```
username: scott
password: tiger
```

But above credentials get:

> Test Failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

It has not asked anything while installing SQL Developer.

Comment: @AlexPoole i don't have any database. just putting some random name to create it.

Comment: @AlexPoole it does not help me. there are suggesting to install oracle express edition i have already installed, now how do i connect it. please help me

Comment: you must already have a database, the real problem is either there is no SCOTT user in your database, or you have the wrong password.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith i dont have any database

Comment: the database is saying Test Failed: ORA-01017: invalid, not SQL Developer

Comment: @thatjeffsmith i dont know my database as i am beginner in sql i have installed both applications . now how i connect with any databse

Comment: show us your connection properties, we can probably 'guess' what kind of database you are working with then

Comment: for anyone else reading, almost no database will have a working 'SCOTT" schema, it's generally seen as a security risk